# How to fetch data from returned jsonp from Facebook API for cover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a function which is taking user id and calling the FB graph API for cover image, the API call is correct I am getting the cover image url but that url is not getting stored in `var timlineimagepath`. I had tried every possible scope for that variable

```
var timelineimgpath;

function getFBTimelineImgPath(userid) {
    var URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userid + '?fields=cover';
    var path = $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (parsed_json) {
            return (timelineimgpath = parsed_json["cover"]["source"]);
        }
    }
});
```

I am calling this function from another function but there the `timelineimgpath` is coming `UNDEFINED`.

Comment: try putting console.log(parsed_json) in success: and see what response comes. Try to nanlyze its structure. Can you give us the returned JSON response string ?

Comment: this timelineimagepath at the point of return contains the url of cover I had checked it with alert statement .but outside when i am using it it's just undefine what into it. and i alsi treid stroing the content into var Path but what i got i a object i don;t know hwta to do with that

Comment: instead of alert(parsed_json) try using console.log(parsed_json) and check the 'console' tab of firebug. It will show up the structure of the returned JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are facing the same problem as on:

- [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

In fact, you won't be able to return anything from an Ajax function because Ajax is asynchronous. Think that every Ajax call takes time and that the next statements don't wait for the Ajax call to finish.

#### 1st solution: using a promise

```
var timelineimgpath;

function getCover(userid) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userid + '?fields=cover',
    });
}

getCover("19292868552").done(function (data) {
    /** You have to do everything you need with your data HERE */
    timelineimgpath = data.cover.source;
    alert(timelineimgpath); // <-- this is called after
});

/** 
 * You see that the data is not available 
 * The Facebook API query has not occured yet!
 */
alert(timelineimgpath); // <-- "undefined"
```

[<kbd>JsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cGwf6/)

---

#### 2nd solution: using a callback

```
function getCover(callback, userid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + userid + '?fields=cover',
        success: callback
    });
}

function doWithCover(data) {
    /** You have to do everything you need with your data HERE */
    alert(data.cover.source);
}

getCover(doWithCover, '19292868552');
```

[<kbd>JsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/du2kH/)

Comment: Same problem data.cover.source contains the cover url but the function from where I am using                                               var timelineimgpath=getgetFBTimelineImgPath('USER_ID'); s

Comment: I updated the code since. Can you make sure you have the following in your code: `return $.ajax` ?

Comment: Ya I had tried the updated code also, now the timelineimgpath var  contains the entire object

Comment: timelineimgpath:object { readyState=1, setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
 
readyState 1 abort
 function()
 
always
 function()
 
complete
 function()
 
done
 function()
 
error
 function()
 
fail
 function()
 
getAllResponseHeaders
 function()
 
getResponseHeader
 function()
 
isRejected
 function()
 
isResolved
 function()
 
overrideMimeType
 function()
 
pipe
 function()
 
progress
 function()
 
promise
 function()
 
setRequestHeader
 function()
 
state
 function()
 
statusCode
 function()
 
success
 function()
 
then
 function()

Comment: On expanding more the inner content is function  this is same to what when i was trying to store the content into var path.

Comment: Ok, I've got it to work and I updated my answer. You can try now.